# Using a dictionary as regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, list, parsing, dictionary

I had a Python question I was hoping for some help on.

Let's start with the important part, here is my current code:

```
import re #for regex
import numpy as np #for matrix

f1 = open('file-to-analyze.txt','r') #file to analyze

#convert files of words into arrays. 
#These words are used to be matched against in the "file-to-analyze"
math = open('sample_math.txt','r')
matharray = list(math.read().split())
math.close()

logic = open('sample_logic.txt','r')
logicarray = list(logic.read().split())
logic.close()

priv = open ('sample_priv.txt','r')
privarray = list(priv.read().split())
priv.close()

... Read in 5 more files and make associated arrays

#convert arrays into dictionaries
math_dict = dict()
math_dict.update(dict.fromkeys(matharray,0))

logic_dict = dict()
logic_dict.update(dict.fromkeys(logicarray,1))

...Make more dictionaries from the arrays (8 total dictionaries - the same number as there are arrays)

#create big dictionary of all keys
word_set = dict(math_dict.items() + logic_dict.items() + priv_dict.items() ... )

statelist = list()

for line in f1:
     for word in word_set:
         for m in re.finditer(word, line):
            print word.value()
```

The goal of the program is to take a large text file and perform analysis on it. Essentially, I want the program to loop through the text file and match words found in Python dictionaries and associate them with a category and keep track of it in a list.

So for example, let's say I was parsing through the file and I ran across the word "ADD". ADD is listed under the "math" or '0' category of words. The program should then add it to a list that it ran across a 0 category and then continue to parse the file. Essentially generating a large list that looks like [0,4,6,7,4,3,4,1,2,7,1,2,2,2,4...] with each of the numbers corresponding to a particular state or category of words as illustrated above. For the sake of understanding, we'll call this large list 'statelist'

As you can tell from my code, so far I can take as input the file to analyze, take and store the text files that contain the list of words into arrays and from there into dictionaries with their correct corresponding list value (a numerical value from 1 - 7). However, I'm having trouble with the analysis portion.

As you can tell from my code, I'm trying to go line by line through the text file and regex any of the found words with the dictionaries. This is done through a loop and regexing with an additional, 9th dictionary that is more or less a "super" dictionary to help simplify the parsing.

However, I'm having trouble matching all the words in the file and when I find the word, matching it to the dictionary value, not the key. That is when it runs across and "ADD" to add 0 to the list because it is a part of the 0 or "math" category.

Would someone be able to help me figure out how to write this script? I really appreciate it! Sorry for the long post, but the code requires a lot of explanation so you know what's going on. Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Update:
Using this loop prints out the word names, but not the category values.

      [for line in f1:
      for word in word_set:
     for m in re.finditer(word, line):
   statelist.append(word)]

Comment: ^Sorry, I was trying to make that a code block in the comments and it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest change to your existing code would just be to just keep track of both the word and the category in the loop:

```
for line in f1:
    for word, category in word_set.iteritems():
        for m in re.finditer(word, line):
            print word, category
            statelist.append(category)
```